# comparing two HEX strings in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am working on loadrunner application there I have to compare two hex strings.
char *s1 = "\x00I\x00N\x00 \x00P\x00R\x00O\x00G\x00R\x00E\x00S\x00S";
char *s2 = "\x00C\x00O\x00M\x00P\x00L\x00E\x00T\x00E\x00D";

above are the strings I tried some String functions like strcmp, stricmp.. but they are not useful because of escape sequence character in string('\')

Can you please help.

Thanks,
S.ai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two are not normal C strings as they contain null characters `\x00` in their bodies. `strcmp()` cannot work with them as it would find null character at the beginning and assume they have zero length. Try [memcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) instead.

Comment: Thanx #tserg42 It really helps alot.